# Processing.js fonts not loading

Tags: fonts, processing, loading, processing.js

I'm making a game in Processing.js, and I need to add two custom fonts. The second one I load works fine (OXYGENE1.TTF). However the first one I load doesn't work at all (CenturyGothic.ttf).

Here is my code:

`/* @pjs font="CenturyGothic.ttf,OXYGENE1.TTF"; */`

I have checked the URLS over and over, even copying and pasting the name of the file. It's in the same directory as the other one, so I shouldn't need to add a folder, right? This is for a game jam.

Comment: Processing.js has been shut down (I archived it at the start of December 2018), and will never receive updates or support again. Please don't start any new projects with it, especially not hackjams where you want to find answers quickly. Have a look at p5.js instead over on https://p5js.org for a modern web-based Processing-like, with a large community, and a ton of tutorial work by Daniel Shiffman.

Comment: Rest in peace my childhood. (I grew up on Processing.js)

Comment: It filled an important gap at the time, but that gap has basically disappeared. P5js is _pretty sweet_ though, check it out if you hadn't already (and the "coding train" video series by Shiffman is kinda of great? Some episodes are in P5, others p5js, but it's rare that you don't learn _something_ even if you already know "how to do that thing he's doing")

Comment: How different is it from processing.js? I don’t want to have to rewrite my whole project, but I will definitely check it out.

Comment: it's a bit more native JS, which frankly is super nice because it means all the quirks of Pjs that existed because JS isn't Java don't come into play. There's some syntax and conventiion differences, but nothing so big it makes porting a project a chore, I'd say (unless it's a huge project, in which case _every_ refactor is a chore =)

Comment: Okay, thanks! I’ll check it out.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Aaah I knew Processing.js was not maintained anymore, but it's still sad to hear it from an official source. Do you have any interest in updating the Processing.js site to recommend folks use pure Processing or P5.js? I put [this article](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/which-processing) together a while ago, but it would be nice to have an "official" source to point to for future questions about Processing.js.

Comment: The way the site builds has been a black hole mystery for years (which is why it's not saying 1.6.6 is the last release, nothing I do seems to update the actual page content) but https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js mentions p5js